# Associative Containers with int as key in .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I have a bunch of different kind of objects, all of which being build at the beginning of the execution.

```
SimpleWidget : Widget, ComplexWidget : Widget
Country
PathToListing
ProductsSoldCount
```

I have a simple way to generate a unique `int ID` for each of these objects.

I intend to keep track of each object created at the beginning of the execution in a dedicated collection, using `ID` as a key. `ID`s may or may not be in consecutive order (for exemple, `ProductsSoldCount`'s `ID` is build from a combination to `Country`'s  and `Widget`'s `ID`s.

In both cases, which .NET's container is the most appropriate, as far as efficiency is concerned? I don't have to ever clone my containers, just add and lookup.

I think about `List` in the consecutive order case, and maybe `Dictionary<int, T>` or `KeyedCollection<int, T>` for the second case?

Comment: `Dictionary<int, T>` seems to fit your case.

Comment: you mean, in both cases?

Comment: the IDs are 0, 1, ... or in nonconsecutive order like 2001 -> 2050, 4001 -> 4050...

Comment: as long as the integer keys in specific `Dictionary` are distinct, their values are not important

Comment: I get that. But isn't it faster to get the values from a List if the keys are from 0 to N-1 (N being the number of created objects)?